# Java SE generics documentation

Tags: java, generics, terminology

[Heap Pollution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/non-reifiable-varargs-type.html#heap_pollution)

documentation says in the last paragraph of this section that `The static type second formal parameter of the add method is String, but this method is called with an actual parameter of a different type, Integer.` the `add(int,Object)` is called on `l` which static type is `List<Number>` as doc says. could someone please explain why static type is `String` when it seems that it is `Number`.

Thanks,
George

> Heap Pollution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static type of `ls` is `List<String>` because that is what it was defined as.

Using type erasure allows you to change the static type.  When this is done incorrectly, you can get "heap pollution."

Answer (score 3):

the code in the link is:

```
List l = new ArrayList<Number>();
List<String> ls = l;       // unchecked warning
l.add(0, new Integer(42)); // another unchecked warning
String s = ls.get(0);      // ClassCastException is thrown
```

The "tricky" part is

```
List l
```

It defines a variable of type List but witout a type so the compiler (due to java generics implementation) "loses" the type. From that instruction the information about the type is lost and java allows you to do "almost anything".
With the assignment

```
List<String> ls = l;
```

you create a ls as array of string so when it calls

```
l.add(0, new Integer(42));
```

it could be as an alias of

ls.add(0, new Integer(42));

which it means that you are adding an Integer to an array of Strings